# ROR: Mapping array to get value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a small help on ROR.

I have a return from a query and when I do `puts result.to_a`, I have got:

```
{"clazz_id"=>1, "staff_id"=>1}
{"clazz_id"=>2, "staff_id"=>1}
{"clazz_id"=>3, "staff_id"=>1}
```

I have like to convert it to an array of [1, 2, 3] from clazz_id and how can I achieve that?

Comment: `result.to_a.map{|e| e["clazz_id"] }`

Comment: How did you get this result and how do you intend to use it? Generally speaking this would not be the outcome of a query so a better understanding might result in far better answers.

Comment: @engineersmnky, for now I will just use the the answer provided below.      I am very new to ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if use Active record query can make this direct **pluck**

```
results.pluck(:clazz_id)
```

if you need deal with array of hash can use **map** or **map!** like

```
p results.to_a.map{|e| e["clazz_id"] }
```

or can use **collect**

```
p results.to_a.collect{|e| e["clazz_id"] }
```

Comment: [#collect is an alias for #map.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-collect)